# Step 160 on Carousel 10257, white hinges not connecting?

Tags: building, sets

I'm struggling with step 160 where I use white "hinge" connectors to connect the carousel platform sections. It seems to create too much pressure and the platform breaks apart. Grateful for any tips.

[image: Step 160]

Comment: If you share a photo of your model at step 159, someone who has the set might be able to identify if you've made a mistake.

Comment: @Craig That's a great suggestion. I wonder if a live build like this might also provide some insight: https://youtu.be/Qt1Zq-3sGrM?t=2h1m25s

Comment: Have you double checked your construction of each section, especially the positioning of the white edge bricks that the “hinge” connectors are adjacent to?

Comment: Your description is not very detailed, but maybe you just need to press the 12 tan trapezoidal assemblies together (radially) to reduce the circumfence. There shouldn't be any gaps between the bricks. (It's a little bit difficult to explain with words) As @Craig said, please share a photo of your model

Answer (score 2):

There should be **no pressure** on any segment at this step. I fear as some people have commented that something is wrong with either the assembly or perhaps the manufacturing of the parts.

*But*, seeing as it sounds like this occurs with any of the 12 pieces, and it would be unrealistic to assume that all twelve hinges are malformed.

My guess is that the "underbelly" is set together in the wrong configuration, so I would inspect them all to check if they are all identical (in pairs ofc) and matches the guide. If assembly as you describe is possible but breaks, its possible that one of then are oversized.

[image: Instruction 141]

Answer (score 0):

I would go back and check just to make sure that you have done the last **few** steps right. If you still can't figure it out, look on either YouTube or Google and type "LEGO 10257 Carousel Not Working correctly". If there is nothing there, contact LEGO Customer Service and ask for help. Good Luck!